# Why Initiate a pointer variable in member function of a class again?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, heap-memory, allocation

this might a stupid question, but I'm finding it hard to understand why do we need to initiate the pointer variable into the class public member function again, even it is declared in the private section of the class.

This is the basic code of what I'm trying to ask.

```
class Human{
private:
    std::string *name;
    int *age;
public:
    Human(std::string iname, int iage){
        name = new std::string;
        age = new int;

        *name = iname;
        *age = iage;
        std::cout<<"Constructor Called \n \n";
    }

    void display(){
        std::cout<<"My name is "<<*name<<" And my Age is "<<*age<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    }

    ~Human(){
        delete name;
        delete age;
        std::cout<<"Destructor Called \n \n";
    }
};

int main(){
    Human *noor = new Human("Noor", 10);
    noor->display();
    delete noor;
}
```

With the above code, the output is working just as expected, just if I comment the dynamic allocation of pointer on Human Constructor . i.e

```
Human(std::string iname, int iage){
   // name = new std::string;
   // age = new int;

    *name = iname;
    *age = iage;
    std::cout<<"Constructor Called \n \n";
}
```

There is a close program warning on command prompt after successful compilation.

Comment: It is an instance variable. The pointer should point to a valid memory before using it to store data in the memory.

Comment: `*name = iname;` is a bug because name is not pointing to anything.

Comment: Why you are using pointers at all in this code? It would be much better if pointers were not used inside Human. Also modern c++ discourages the use of new.

Comment: A variables need to be initialised, private or public, pointer or non-pointer. I guess I don't understand your question. BTW there is no *again*, in your working code `name` is initialised once. `*name = iname` is not an initialisation of `name`, it's an assignment to what `name` is pointing at.

Comment: @drescherjm  for learning dynamic allocations. (Newbie in programming)

Comment: It's a practice you should forget quickly after learning (or at least avoid usage).. Modern c++ encourages the usage of containers also smart pointers but avoid naked pointers.

Comment: @NoorMohammad It might be better to learn about it in a context where it is useful. Variable length arrays or linked lists for instance.

Comment: You question sounds like by changing 2 lines of code you still have a working code. You don't.

Comment: `std::string *name;` nope. nope. nope. Please don't do this. nope

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I understood the curve.

It is as in private section the pointer is just been declared and no memory is being allocated to the pointer. So we did allocate the memory for the pointer in constructor.

alternatively, we can directly allocate the memory in the private section as well.

i.e:

```
class Human{
private:
    std::string *name = new std::string;
    int *age = new int;
    .....
    .....
 };
```

Thanks Everyone who responded.

Comment: "_It is as in private section_" The behavior of such code is completely unrelated to whether the code is in `private`, `public`, or `protected` sections of your class..

Comment: In general, a pointer just keeps an integral value that is likely the address of some object. There's no guarantee that the integral value IS indeed the address of any valid object. For example, the pointer variable's value could be 0, which is NULL. Besides the pointer, an object is needed. Allocating a pointer does not mean allocating an object. There are multiple ways to allocate an object. One way is to make the object in heap, which the "new SomeObjectType" does. That returns the address of the new object in heap, which can be kept in a pointer variable as its value.